# Batch Image Labelling

Tags: images, adobe-photoshop, batch-file, imagemagick

I have an image I would like to make 50-100 copies of, but for each copy a label is added in the form of a number corresponding to the copy number.

Is there existing software that does this?
Is there a way to do this efficiently?

At the moment I am manually editing and saving each copy with photoshop.

Answer (score 0):

`Imagemagick` springs to mind. It's free and runs on every operating system of interest, including Windows and Linux. Here's the blurb:

> ImageMagick® is a software suite to create, edit, compose, or convert
>   bitmap images. It can read and write images in a variety of formats
>   (over 100) including DPX, EXR, GIF, JPEG, JPEG-2000, PDF, PhotoCD,
>   PNG, Postscript, SVG, and TIFF. Use ImageMagick to resize, flip,
>   mirror, rotate, distort, shear and transform images, adjust image
>   colors, apply various special effects, or **draw text**, lines, polygons,
>   ellipses and Bézier curves.

It's a command line tool and therefore eminiently scriptable - provided you can read the documentation. (It's too late at night for me to try. ;) )

EDIT: Aww, shucks. Here's an example command that will annotate `AngryCat.jpg` with the text `Copy 1` in the top left corner, producing output `AngryCat_Copy1.jpg`:

```
convert AngryCat.jpg -annotate 90 "Copy 1" AngryCat_Copy1.jpg
```

[Documentation for `-annotate`.](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#annotate) To do this 50 times, you just need a script that will vary the annotation text `Copy 1` through `1-50` and the output filename `AngryCat_Copy1.jpg` through `1-50`. (If you tell us what platform you're on, i.e. Win XP, Win 7, Linux, OSX, we might be able to provide an actual batch script.)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I used a similar piece of software XnView actually. Did almost what I wanted, but had to make 100 copies of the image first.

Comment: Did it actually solve the question you originally asked? If so you should write it up as an answer to the question.

Comment: Not strictly no, I may add that stipulation to the original question. It still involves making the copies first then converting the copied files, which is a bit sloppy